# How can I install keras using anaconda with mxnet backend

Tags: keras, anaconda, amazon-ami, mxnet

How can I set keras's backend to be MXNet?

I have found only [this installation guide](https://github.com/deep-learning-tools/keras/wiki/Installation-Guide---Keras-with-MXNet-backend), but after I install keras by hand in this way, Anaconda does not recognize this installation.

In other words, this command:

```
KERAS_BACKEND=mxnet python -c "from keras import backend"
```

works only in the "keras" installation folder.

Therefore, I can not use keras in a Jupyter Notebook, for example.

Do you know another way to install keras in order to be compatible with mxnet (as it is for example on aws's AMIs) ?

Comment: Note that the mxnet backend is not official, so there is no really keras + mxnet supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install keras for a given Anaconda env by first activating that env and then calling

```
pip install -e .
```

in keras folder.  In the guide that you included the link to, this command would replace

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

which installs it system wide.